# Javascript: Trying to sample from multiple arrays without matches, loop increments when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to randomise the presentation of letterstrings in an experiment. Ideally, I'd have javascript create an array of a specified length including all the stimuli for the experiment.

Because some of the strings are variants of each other, there are some matches I'd like to avoid. Not all arrays are have variants, but for those that do, the order is maintained, so that X[i] is a variant of Y[i].

For clarity's sake I'll outline the matches I'd like to avoid. If an item in position *i* is in the target array, the items from position *i* of these arrays should not be included. These relationships are symmetrical

> letterstring_stimuli_a[i] cannot be included with exemplar_flavoured_a[i] or
>   ambiguousb[i]
>
> letterstring_stimuli_b[i] cannot be included with exemplar_flavoured_b[i] or
>   ambiguousa[i].
>
> rule_flavoureda[i] cannot be included with rule_flavouredb[i]

Participants are trained on a random sample of letterstring_training_a and letterstring_training_b, this array is stimuli_random_order. This is why the code refers to an array you can't see (I thought I'd free up space by leaving that code out)

I've set up a for loop that should only increment when items are added to the target array (in this case its 'transfer_random') so that I end up with an array of length 12. Yet when I run the script I get arrays that often have length <12. I'm not sure why this is the case.

I've been running into this problem for a few days now (I'm not a programmer, my javascript is poor).

Why is the loop creating arrays of lengths <12, and how can I fix this?

```
//def array search function to use to make sure that items aren't repeated
function include(arr,obj) {
    return (arr.indexOf(obj) != -1);
}


//stimuli
//training stimuli
var letterstimuli_training_a = ['<p>Spaksvot</p>' ,'<p>Nosedont</p>', '<p>Quitinoct</p>', '<p>Peatikit</p>'];

var letterstimuli_training_b = ['<p>Blasimark</p>', '<p>Lonsink</p>', '<p>Martwok</p>', '<p>Zarbarak</p>'];

//ambiguous transfer
var ambiguousb = ['<p>Spaksvok</p>' ,'<p>Nosedonk</p>', '<p>Quitinock</p>', '<p>Peatikik</p>'];

var ambiguousa = ['<p>Blasimart</p>', '<p>Lonsint</p>', '<p>Martwot</p>', '<p>Zarbarat</p>'];

//exemplar flavoured transfer items defined by their base group
var exemplar_flavoureda = ['<p>Spaksvog</p>' ,'<p>Nosedong</p>', '<p>Quitinocg</p>', '<p>Peatikig</p>']; 
var exemplar_flavouredb = ['<p>Blasimarg</p>', '<p>Lonsing</p>', '<p>Martwog</p>', '<p>Zarbarag</p>'];

//rule flavoured transfer
var rule_flavoureda = ['<p>Dregot</p>', '<p>Flowsat</p>', '<p>Graflat</p>', '<p>Joshwat</p>']
var rule_flavouredb = ['<p>Dregok</p>', '<p>Flowsak</p>', '<p>Graflak</p>', '<p>Joshwak</p>']

//stimuli order with answers and description strings

var stimuli_random_order = [];
var answers = [];
var text_answers = [];

var transfer_random = [];
var transfer_answers = [];
var transfer_text_answers = [];
//randomly populate transfer array

for(var i = 0; i<12; i++) {
    if(Math.floor(Math.random()*7)===0){
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*stimuli_random_order.length)
        if(include(transfer_random, stimuli_random_order[random])) {i--} //no doubles
        else if(include(stimuli_random_order, transfer_random[i-2]) & include(stimuli_random_order, transfer_random[i-1])){i--} //no more than three in a row
        else if(include(transfer_random, exemplar_flavoureda, random)) {i--} //if the variant of this item from exemplara is already in the array, go back
        else if(include(transfer_random, ambiguousb, random)) {i--}
        else {
            transfer_random.push(stimuli_random_order[random])
            transfer_answers.push(answers[random])
            transfer_text_answers.push(text_answers[random])
        }
    }
    else if(Math.floor(Math.random()*7)===1) {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*exemplar_flavoureda.length)
        if(include(transfer_random, exemplar_flavoureda[random])) {i--}
        else if(include(exemplar_flavoureda, transfer_random[i-2]) & include(exemplar_flavoureda, transfer_random[i-1])) {i--}
        else if(include(transfer_random, letterstimuli_training_a[random])) {i--}
        else if(include(transfer_random, ambiguousb[random])) {i--}
        else {
            transfer_random.push(exemplar_flavoureda[random])
            transfer_answers.push(90)
            transfer_text_answers.push('ambiguous a base')
        }
    } 
    else if(Math.floor(Math.random()*7)===2) {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*exemplar_flavouredb.length)
        if(include(transfer_random, exemplar_flavouredb[random])) {i--}
        else if(include(exemplar_flavouredb, transfer_random[i-2]) & include(exemplar_flavouredb, transfer_random[i-1])) {i--}
        else if(include(transfer_random, ambiguousa[random])) {i--}
        else if(include(transfer_random, letterstimuli_training_b[random])) {i--}
        else {
            transfer_random.push(exemplar_flavouredb[random])
            transfer_answers.push(191)
            transfer_text_answers.push('ambiguous b base')
        }
    }
    else if(Math.floor(Math.random()*7)===3) {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*ambiguousa.length)
        if(include(transfer_random, ambiguousa[random])) {i--}
        else if(include(ambiguousa, transfer_random[i-2]) & include(ambiguousa, transfer_random[i-1])) {i--}
        else if(include(transfer_random, letterstimuli_training_a[random])) {i--}
        else if(include(transfer_random, exemplar_flavoureda[random])) {i--}
        else {
            transfer_random.push(ambiguousa[random])
            transfer_answers.push(90)
            transfer_text_answers.push('category a')
        }
    }
    else if(Math.floor(Math.random()*7)===4) {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*ambiguousb.length)
        if(include(transfer_random, ambiguousb[random])) {i--}
        else if(include(ambiguousb, transfer_random[i-2]) & include(ambiguousb, transfer_random[i-1])) {i--}
        else if(include(transfer_random, letterstimuli_training_b[random])) {i--}
        else if(include(transfer_random, exemplar_flavouredb[random])) {i--}
        else {
            transfer_random.push(ambiguousb[random])
            transfer_answers.push(191)
            transfer_text_answers.push('category b')
        }
    }
    else if(Math.floor(Math.random()*7)===5) {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*rule_flavoureda.length)
        if(include(transfer_random, rule_flavoureda[random])) {i--}
        else if(include(rule_flavoureda, transfer_random[i-2]) & include(rule_flavoureda, transfer_random[i-1])) {i--}
        else if(include(transfer_random, rule_flavouredb[random])) {i--}
        else {
            transfer_random.push(rule_flavoureda[random])
            transfer_answers.push(90)
            transfer_text_answers.push('category a')
        }
    }
    else if(Math.floor(Math.random()*7)===6) {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*rule_flavouredb.length)
        if(include(transfer_random, rule_flavouredb[random]) ){i--}
        else if(include(rule_flavouredb, transfer_random[i-2]) & include(rule_flavouredb, transfer_random[i-1])) {i--}
        else if(include(transfer_random, rule_flavoureda[random])) {i--}
        else {
            transfer_random.push(rule_flavouredb[random])
            transfer_answers.push(191)
            transfer_text_answers.push('category b')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is an error with your if/else logic - you are checking a new random value in each condition, so it is possible (even likely) that at least 1 out of the 12 iterations will never answer a condition.
What you need to do is save the random value into a variable at the start of each iteration, and then check it in each condition:

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*7);
if( rand === 0 ){/*code*/}
else if( rand === 1){/*code*/}
....
else if( rand === 6){/*code*/}
```